# Getting window-icon to work with Zenity

Tags: 14.04, launcher, zenity

I am having a weird problem with Zenity. I've never used Zenity before, so this could be a mistake. If I type the command `zenity --question --text=QUESTIONGOESHERE --window-icon=/some/path/to/64x64/.png/file` that should make it so that the icon (.png) will appear on the launcher as the icon for Zenity, no? It's not working. Does it need to have different dimensions? Can it not be a .png or something? I need help. The icon just doesn't display.

Comment: I'm sure there is some stupidly obvious answer to this but I don't know it.

Comment: It is a (long standing) bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zenity/+bug/998491

Comment: Well, that's a good enough answer for me.

Comment: I would recommend using [YAD](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/yad-zenity-on-steroids-display.html) over Zenity. Aside from fixing annoying issues like this it comes with an impressive number of new features.

Comment: YAD looks good, but it's not in the official repos, Not even in 14.04. I'm using Zenity (now YAD) to make a program for an open source project I'm making, and if I make it with YAD I will have to make YAD a dependency. People would get dependency resolution errors every time they try to install my packages. As a little workaround, I will just make a launcher that starts my script, making it behave like Zenity would if it did what it was supposed to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `--window-icon` parameter isn't meant to set the image displayed in the info/warning/message/question dialogs, but the gtk-window icon. You can confirm that this is set using `xprop`.

This means that there is currently no answer to this. If you are willing to modify the code and compile it yourself, I have added a patch to the [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zenity/+bug/998491) on launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zenity/+bug/998491/+attachment/4293554/+files/image-fix.patch

This changes it, so that --window-icon not only sets the window icon, but also the dialog image:

[image: zenity-fix]

Answer (score 3):

(answer take from this [source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234538))

This was tested on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with zenity version `3.18.1.1`

If you want to change the dialog icon with one of the stock icons you can use the undocumented option `--icon-name`:

```
zenity --icon-name='dialog-warning' --question --title='Title' --text='Test text'
```

This is the result:

[image]

You can use any of the names in the list of [GNOME standard icon names](https://developer.gnome.org/icon-naming-spec/#names).